# Javadoc sample/template on Spring framework and html/xml file

Tags: java, spring, documentation, javadoc

Now working on a J2EE project using Spring Framework in Eclipse. We would like to prepare the in-source doc by Javadoc and have the following questions: 1) Since Spring framework use a lot of annotation and difficult to follow for new comers, any doc template/guideline to write in-source doc so that its easier for new comer to follow?

2) Apart from .java file, our project involve many html (with Thymeleaf) and xml files, so that we would like to generate doc for those html/xml file as well (many settings in the persistence.xml are difficult to follow after 2 weeks if not documented) Any method for JavaDoc to support those html/xml files ?

3) If not use JavaDoc any other component(s) in Eclipse for documentation ?

Thanks.

LAM Chi-fung

Answer (score 0):

I think you need more than only JavaDoc, so please have a look at [AsciiDoc](http://asciidoc.org/) and it's extensions.

Comment: Thanks, I've added AsciiDoc and AsciiDoctor editor extension for Eclipse, but is there any template for program doc ? AsciiDoc only define title, subtitle and author etc. Or any example on using AsciiDoc with Eclipse and Spring project.

Comment: There are a lot of examples out there - with extensions you could for example also generate UML diagrams from asciidoc into your documents.